# Function to compute 3D gradient with unevenly spaced sample locations

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, data-manipulation, gradient

I have experimental observations in a volume:

```
import numpy as np

# observations are not uniformly spaced 
x = np.random.normal(0, 1, 10)
y = np.random.normal(5, 2, 10)
z = np.random.normal(10, 3, 10)
xx, yy, zz = np.meshgrid(x, y, z, indexing='ij')

# fake temperatures at those coords
tt = xx*2 + yy*2 + zz*2

# sample distances
dx = np.diff(x)
dy = np.diff(y)
dz = np.diff(z)

grad = np.gradient(tt, [dx, dy, dz])  # returns error
```

This gives me the error:

> `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (10,10,10) (3,9) (10,10,10)`.

EDIT: according to @jay-kominek in the comments below:

> np.gradient won't work for you, it simply doesn't handle unevenly sampled data.

I've updated the question. Is there any function which can can do my computation?

Comment: Just saw that y-axis is not linearly spaced. You might have to interpolate that on a linear grid.

Comment: Note that  `linspace` suffers from fencepost  error relative to `np.arange`, so to get 0.1 difference you need 11, 9, 5 `posts`.

Comment: I updated the question and title to make it clear that the spacings are not uniform

Comment: Hi Roving, I have a very similar question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40338386/calculating-a-3d-gradient-with-unevenly-spaced-points); I was wondering if you ever found an adequate solution.

Comment: @brokenseas, No, I never did

Answer (score 3):

Two things to note: First, scalars are single values, not arrays. Second, the signature of the function is `numpy.gradient(f, *varargs, **kwargs)`. Note the * before `varargs`. That means if `varargs` is a list, you pass `*varargs`. Or you can just provide the elements of `varargs` as separate arguments.

So, `np.gradient` wants a single value for the distance along each dimension, like:

```
np.gradient(tt, np.diff(x)[0], np.diff(y)[0], np.diff(z)[0])
```

or:

```
distances = [np.diff(x)[0], np.diff(y)[0], np.diff(z)[0]]
np.gradient(tt, *distances)
```

Comment: Nice, clean explanation.

Comment: or just `(x[1] - x[0]), (y[1] - y[0]), (z[1] - z[0])` to avoid calculating redundant differences when `x` is large.

Comment: Hi Jay, this answer as it stands assums the diffs are constant. I updated the question and example to make it clear that the data is unevenly sampled.

Comment: @RovingRichard `np.gradient` won't work for you, it simply doesn't handle unevenly sampled data. https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L1380

Answer (score 0):

The required dx ... to be passed to `np.gradient` aren't grids of differences, but just one scalar each.   So `grad = np.gradient(tt,0.1,0.1,0.1)`appears to work.

Comment: It works for me, but I get an unchanging output, when the analytical solution should be [2x, 2y,2z].

Comment: Hey roadrunner66, I updated the question to reflect that the observations aren't linearly spaced.